# What does status "Undisclosed" means for a conference paper

Tags: conference

I had sent a paper in a reputed conference. The status changed from "Under review" to "Decision pending" to "Undisclosed".

What is the meaning of status "Undisclosed" ? Does it indicate something?

Comment: It indicates that the conference system has a tendency to provide useless information that will, at best, send some of the authors round the bend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Undisclosed" means that the conference chair (or the in-charge of decisions) has already made a decision based on the comments received from the reviewers, but the decision is not yet made visible to the authors.

Wait for the decision notification date. You can see it on that date.